# php read xml content from soap with getElementsByTagNameNS

Tags: php, xml, soap, domdocument

This is my XML which i have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Body>
  <notifications xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound">
   <OrganizationId>00Dp00000008kXDEAY</OrganizationId>
   <ActionId>04k28000000L3shAAC</ActionId>
   <SessionId xsi:nil="true"/>
   <EnterpriseUrl>https://232.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/36.0/00Dp00000008kXD</EnterpriseUrl>
   <PartnerUrl>https://232.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/36.0/00Dp00000008kXD</PartnerUrl>
   <Notification>
    <Id>034l3004D4247lVAAS</Id>
    <sObject xsi:type="sf:SMS_Activity__c" xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
     <sf:Id>a0Ip0000001WxvaEAC</sf:Id>
     <sf:Brand__c>ABC</sf:Brand__c>
     <sf:Content__c>halo test</sf:Content__c>
     <sf:Mobile__c>628145783535</sf:Mobile__c>
    </sObject>
   </Notification>
  </notifications>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Please help me how to read the value of (brand,content__C,mobile__c)
with php code ?

I could not get Mobile__c that from what i tried the below code

```
 $notif=simplexml_load_string($xml);
      $Mobile=$notif->sObject-
      >children('urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com')-
      >Mobile__c.PHP_EOL;
      $qd="";
      $qd="insert into incoming(phone) values('$Mobile')";
      mysql_query($qd);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this hope this will help you out..

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/786044)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$string='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Body>
  <notifications xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound">
   <OrganizationId>00Dp00000008kXDEAY</OrganizationId>
   <ActionId>04k28000000L3shAAC</ActionId>
   <SessionId xsi:nil="true"/>
   <EnterpriseUrl>https://232.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/36.0/00Dp00000008kXD</EnterpriseUrl>
   <PartnerUrl>https://232.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/36.0/00Dp00000008kXD</PartnerUrl>
   <Notification>
    <Id>034l3004D4247lVAAS</Id>
    <sObject xsi:type="sf:SMS_Activity__c" xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
     <sf:Id>a0Ip0000001WxvaEAC</sf:Id>
     <sf:Brand__c>ABC</sf:Brand__c>
     <sf:Content__c>halo test 1</sf:Content__c>
     <sf:Mobile__c>6281457835351</sf:Mobile__c>
    </sObject>
   </Notification> <Notification>
    <Id>034l3004D4247lVAAS</Id>
    <sObject xsi:type="sf:SMS_Activity__c" xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
     <sf:Id>a0Ip0000001WxvaEAC</sf:Id>
     <sf:Brand__c>ABC2</sf:Brand__c>
     <sf:Content__c>halo test 2</sf:Content__c>
     <sf:Mobile__c>6281457835352</sf:Mobile__c>
    </sObject>
   </Notification> <Notification>
    <Id>034l3004D4247lVAAS</Id>
    <sObject xsi:type="sf:SMS_Activity__c" xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
     <sf:Id>a0Ip0000001WxvaEAC</sf:Id>
     <sf:Brand__c>ABC3</sf:Brand__c>
     <sf:Content__c>halo test 3</sf:Content__c>
     <sf:Mobile__c>6281457835353</sf:Mobile__c>
    </sObject>
   </Notification>
  </notifications>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';

$requiredData=array();
$result= new DOMDocument();
$result->loadXML($string);
foreach(array(
    "Brand__c",
    "Content__c",
    "Mobile__c"
) as $key)
{
    foreach($result->getElementsByTagNameNS("urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com",$key) as $element)
    {
        if($element instanceof DOMElement)
        {   
           $requiredData[$element->tagName][] =$element->textContent;
        }
    }
}
print_r($requiredData);
```

Comment: thank you .. but how to get directly accesing to  Mobile__C, i confuse using $expectedOutput[$child->tagName], i try to replace with $expectedOutput[sf:Mobile__c] but error. i am sorry, i am new to php xml. thank you a lot

Comment: @Def Thanks friend... :) just remove your above comment doesnt sounds good... Thanks again

Comment: Mr sahil , sorry to disturb again,if i have more than one data like below, how to access it through loop ?

Comment: @Def can you share that sample XML?

Comment: <Notification><Id>04lp0000004D7nEAAS</Id><sObject xsi:type="sf:SMS_Activity__c" xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com"><sf:Id>1232</sf:Id><sf:Brand__c>ABC</sf:Brand__c><sf:Content__c> administrator testing</sf:Content__c><sf:Mobile__c>124</sf:Mobile__c></sObject>
  </Notification><Notification><Id>125</Id><sObject xsi:type="sf:SMS_Activity__c" xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com"><sf:Id>a0Ip0000001WxyLEAS</sf:Id><sf:Brand__c>ABF</sf:Brand__c><sf:Content__c> administrator testing </sf:Content__c><sf:Mobile__c>123</sf:Mobile__c></sObject></Notification>

Comment: Mr sahil, sorry whole xml not enough to put in this comment , you can see more complete below your answer.

Comment: @Def In `Asia/Kolkata` its lunch time back to you soon sorryy

Comment: Enjoy your luch @Sahil

Comment: i test your code looks good, but i am really beginner in PHP, how to acces and store value in variable ? $brand=$requiredData[$element->tagName][]; $mobile=$requiredData[$element->tagName][];

Comment: you can check `$element->tagName`, if it is related to mobile then you can put it into mobile array and soo on...

Answer (score 0):

Mr sahil , sorry to disturb again,if i have more than one data like below, how to access it through loop ?

```
<Notification>
    <Id>034l3004D4247lVAAS</Id>
    <sObject xsi:type="sf:SMS_Activity__c" xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
     <sf:Id>a0Ip0000001WxvaEAC</sf:Id>
     <sf:Brand__c>ABC</sf:Brand__c>
     <sf:Content__c>halo test 1</sf:Content__c>
     <sf:Mobile__c>6281457835351</sf:Mobile__c>
    </sObject>
   </Notification> <Notification>
    <Id>034l3004D4247lVAAS</Id>
    <sObject xsi:type="sf:SMS_Activity__c" xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
     <sf:Id>a0Ip0000001WxvaEAC</sf:Id>
     <sf:Brand__c>ABC2</sf:Brand__c>
     <sf:Content__c>halo test 2</sf:Content__c>
     <sf:Mobile__c>6281457835352</sf:Mobile__c>
    </sObject>
   </Notification> <Notification>
    <Id>034l3004D4247lVAAS</Id>
    <sObject xsi:type="sf:SMS_Activity__c" xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
     <sf:Id>a0Ip0000001WxvaEAC</sf:Id>
     <sf:Brand__c>ABC3</sf:Brand__c>
     <sf:Content__c>halo test 3</sf:Content__c>
     <sf:Mobile__c>6281457835353</sf:Mobile__c>
    </sObject>
   </Notification>
```